# How can I use 'gulp-babel' throw ERROR don't stop node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

When I use `gulp-babel` to compile my js code,if I don't finish my code,

for examle:`for(let i =)`

I will press `ctrl+s`,`gulp-babel`will throw Error,like the pic:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX7Rl.png)

How can I do,when `gulp-babel` throw ERROR,don't stop the node server,just throw ERROR.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to handle the errors, so for example if you have the next gulp task:

```
gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

you would need to add `.on('error', handleError)` right after you use the `babel` plugin so your code ends up like this:

```
function handleError (error) {
    console.log(error.toString());
    this.emit('end');
}

gulp.task('default', () => {
    return gulp.src('src/app.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

The important bit is `this.emit('end');` which will allow your tasks to continue working after the errors. `handleError` is just a helper function, I believe you can use it after all gulp plugins, I've used it with babel, typescript, rollup, etc. so it can probably be used with others as well.

Comment: I find a plugin is awsome to handle error ,  gulp-plumber, https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber/